# Multiple labels through array

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsmutablearray, nsarray

[image]

I want to add multiple labels in my view according to objects in array.
The image shows what I want to do.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/t44V1.png
this is the image link

Answer (score -1):

You need to something like that;

```
let labelArray: [String] = ["Label1", "Label2", "Label3", "Label4"]

for k in 0..<labelArray.count {
    let headerLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(CGFloat(75*k), 0, 70, 30))
    headerLabel.lineBreakMode = .ByTruncatingTail
    view.addSubview(headerLabel)
}
```